# Does CSS accept folder names with spaces?

Tags: css, directory

I have tried to insert a background image in a CSS archive, the image is in my computer, I tried to put the image address but the editor does not recognize it. When I run the code my background photo does not appear. There is some problem with the spaces in some folder names? The image address is
"**G:/Programação/Webdesign/Curso de Webdesign/Projeto CSS/imagens/bg-3.jpg**". My code editor is Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Please **[edit]** the question and show the **exact CSS** that you tried, not just the file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It accepts folder with spaces it will be %20 in url.

But you should use relative path for your image like `/imagens/bg-3.jpg` or `/Projeto CSS/imagens/bg-3.jpg`